# How to find time spent on each status in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the time spent on each status for each driver. I have already calculated the time difference but it is stored in the wrong cell against the wrong driver.
Please see the data and my approach so far.
Thanks in advance

**My Data**

| id | driver_id | status | entry_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:49 |
| 2 | 200 | Available | 27/07/2022 20:53 |
| 3 | 200 | On-Delivery | 27/07/2022 20:55 |
| 4 | 200 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:57 |
| 5 | 201 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:33 |
| 6 | 201 | Available | 27/07/2022 20:36 |
| 7 | 201 | On-Delivery | 27/07/2022 20:39 |
| 8 | 201 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:44 |

**Output I want**

| id | driver_id | status | entry_time | Output(time spend in minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:49 | 4 |
| 2 | 200 | Available | 27/07/2022 20:53 | 2 |
| 3 | 200 | On-Delivery | 27/07/2022 20:55 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:57 | - |
| 5 | 201 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:33 | 3 |
| 6 | 201 | Available | 27/07/2022 20:36 | 3 |
| 7 | 201 | On-Delivery | 27/07/2022 20:39 | 5 |
| 8 | 201 | Offline | 27/07/2022 20:44 | - |

```
select 
id,
driver_id,
driver_status,
driver_status.entry_time as cur_time,
LEAD(driver_status.entry_time) over (order by driver_status.id)  as next_time,
DATEDIFF(minute,driver_status.entry_time,lead(driver_status.entry_time) over (order by id))  as timespent in minutes
from driver_status;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calls to the `LEAD()` analytic function need a `PARTITION` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    driver_id,
    driver_status,
    entry_time AS cur_time,
    LEAD(entry_time) OVER (PARTITION BY driver_id ORDER BY entry_time) AS next_time,
    DATEDIFF(minute,
             entry_time,
             LEAD(entry_time) OVER (PARTITION BY driver_id ORDER BY entry_time)
    ) AS [timespent in minutes]
FROM driver_status
ORDER BY
    driver_id,
    entry_time;
```